# How to export a symbol from an external module?

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, kernel

I am coding outside the kernel source tree. There are two modules, the first one **printt** have a function `printtty()` to print string to the current tty, and the second module **hello** which invokes `printtty()` during initialization.

I have added `EXPORT_SYMBOL(printtty)` in module **printt**, and after `insmod ./printt.ko`, the information of `printtty()` can be seen in `/proc/kallsyms`.

The `make` process of module **hello** goes all right. But `insmod ./hello.ko` will cause an error like:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module hello.ko: Invalid parameters
```

and `dmesg` shows

```
hello: no symbol version for printtty
hello: Unknown symbol printtty (err -22)`.
```

I've fixed this by

(1) Copy the .ko file to a location beneath /lib/modules/version/kernel

(2) Add the exported symbols to /lib/modules/version/build/Module.symvers

But I wonder is there any way to export a symbol **just from an external module**(without modifying kernel source tree)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this line at the **very top** of your Makefile for your **hello** module:

```
KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS := /home/your-user/path/to/printt/Module.symvers
```

(be sure to put in the correct path to your **printt** module).

Now rebuild your **hello** module and it will be loaded just fine.

For details see [Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt#L469), "6.3 Symbols From Another External Module".