# How to provide custom Module.symvers for new Linux kernels?

Tags: linux, build, module, kernel

Suppose

1. You have a module with several public functions exported to the kernel space by EXPORT_SYMBOL
2. Your other module depends on the abovesaid symbols

Before you would have made a custom Module.symvers containing information about the exported symbols from your first module. It was loaded in the build process and the modpost script worked correctly.

Since 5.6.?? linux kernels this practice changed and it quietly ignores Module.symvers placed in the build directory.

What is the new way to do this thing? I checked that if I add the symbols from my parent module to the system Module.symvers file the dependent module builds, but this is not a long term solution.

P.S.: As for the difference: compare (Linux 5.4.**)

```
    MODPOST = scripts/mod/modpost                                           \
            $(if $(CONFIG_MODVERSIONS),-m)                                  \
            $(if $(CONFIG_MODULE_SRCVERSION_ALL),-a)                        \
            $(if $(KBUILD_EXTMOD),-i,-o) $(kernelsymfile)                   \
->here is it-> $(if $(KBUILD_EXTMOD),-I $(modulesymfile))                      \
            $(if $(KBUILD_EXTMOD),$(addprefix -e ,$(KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS))) \
            $(if $(KBUILD_EXTMOD),-o $(modulesymfile))                      \
            $(if $(CONFIG_SECTION_MISMATCH_WARN_ONLY),,-E)                  \
            $(if $(KBUILD_MODPOST_WARN),-w)                                 \
            $(if $(filter nsdeps,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),-d)
```

To Linux 5.6.**

```
MODPOST = scripts/mod/modpost                                           \
        $(if $(CONFIG_MODVERSIONS),-m)                                  \
        $(if $(CONFIG_MODULE_SRCVERSION_ALL),-a)                        \
        $(if $(KBUILD_EXTMOD),-i,-o) $(kernelsymfile)                   \
        $(if $(KBUILD_EXTMOD),$(addprefix -e ,$(KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS))) \
        $(if $(KBUILD_EXTMOD),-o $(modulesymfile))                      \
        $(if $(CONFIG_SECTION_MISMATCH_WARN_ONLY),,-E)                  \
        $(if $(KBUILD_MODPOST_WARN),-w)
```

Comment: Docs: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/modules.html?highlight=modules%20symvers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export a symbol from an external module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603725/how-to-export-a-symbol-from-an-external-module)

Comment: My thanks. Solved the problem entirely.